# how i get a image from an NSMutableArray and send to my collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray

I have this array:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        topDestinations = [["image": "hotel2.jpeg","name":"Ibiza"],
            ["image": "hotel2.jpeg","name":"huehueuhe"],
            ["image": "hotel2.jpeg","name":"Ibiza"],
            ["image": "hotel2.jpeg","name":"Ibiza"],
            ["image": "hotel2.jpeg","name":"huehueuhe"],
            ["image": "hotel2.jpeg","name":"Ibiza"],
            ["image": "hotel2.jpeg","name":"Ibiza"],
            ["image": "hotel4.jpeg","name":"Ibiza"],
            ["image": "hotel2.jpeg","name":"huehueuhe"],
            ["image": "hotel4.jpeg","name":"Ibiza"],
            ["image": "hotel2.jpeg","name":"Ibiza"],
            ["image": "hotel2.jpeg","name":"Ibiza"],
            ["image": "hotel4.jpeg","name":"Ibiza"],
            ["image": "hotel2.jpeg","name":"Ibiza"],
            ["image": "hotel4.jpeg","name":"huehueuhe"],
            ["image": "hotel2.jpeg","name":"Ibiza"],
            ["image": "hotel2.jpeg","name":"Ibiza"],
            ["image": "hotel2.jpeg","name":"vhuehueuhe"],
            ["image": "hotel4.jpeg","name":"Ibiza"],
            ["image": "hotel4.jpeg","name":"Ibiza"],
            ["image": "hotel4.jpeg","name":"Ibiza"],
            ["image": "hotel2.jpeg","name":"Ibiza"],
            ["image": "hotel2.jpeg","name":"Ibiza"],
            ["image": "hotel4.jpeg","name":"Ibiza"],
            ["image": "hotel4.jpeg","name":"Ibiza"]]
    }
```

I want to get the corresponding picture as cell and assemble it here:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("TopDestinationsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell

        var hotelImageView : UIImageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
        var hotelNameLabel : UILabel = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel

        hotelImageView.image = topDestinations[indexPath.row]["image"] as? UIImage
        hotelNameLabel.text = topDestinations[indexPath.row]["name"] as? String

        return cell
    }
```

The right of the cell name appears correctly but none of the photos appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to actually load the image in the `UIImageView`, not just give the image name to it. This assumes that the image is in the main bundle (you may not need the .jpeg extension for this).

```
hotelImageView.image = UIImage(named: topDestinations[indexPath.row]["image"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make a new UIImage using the image name provided from your data

```
UIImage(named: "imageName.jpg")
```

and then assign that to the image property of your UIImageView